# Documentaion for azure maps to switch map view

Tags: azure-maps

In this release https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/blog/route-matrix-isochrones-ip-lookup-and-more-added-to-azure-maps/ azure map control able to switch views, but seem documentation is not updated, anyone who knows how this can be done from JavaScript
The documentation has only two options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/models.stylecontroloptions?view=azure-iot-typescript-latest#style, which is not the same as in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
map.addControl(new atlas.control.StyleControl(), { position: "top-right" });
```

This will create a control on the map that allows you to switch between the different available modes.